# ng-repeat doesn't work with data in my case

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in my index.html I tried

```
<li ng-repeat="friend in user.relationship">{{friend.name}}</li>
```

and this is my json look like

```
var user = [
        {
        'uId': 1,
        'name': 'me',
        'relationship': 
            [
                {'uId':2,
                 'name': 'Jeremy',
                 'tabs':[{'tabId':1}],
                 'tasks':[{'name':'Im Jeremy Lin'}]
                }
            ]
        }
]
```

I even tried     `<li ng-repeat="friend in user[0].relationship">{{friend[0].name}}</li>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this thing out, since this would be good even for **Single** and **Multiple** objects

```
<ul ng-repeat="friend in user">
  <li ng-repeat="relation in friend.relationship">
    {{relation.name}}             
  </li>
</ul>
```

Say if you have a json like below, you need to print both  **Jeremy, Jasmin**

Take a look at this **[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/uRPSL/33/)**

```
$scope.user = [{
        'uId': 1,
            'name': 'eldy',
            'relationship': [{
            'uId': 2,
                'name': 'Jeremy',
                'tabs': [{
                'tabId': 1
            }],
                'tasks': [{
                'name': 'Im Jeremy Lin'
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        'uId': 2,
            'name': 'eldy1',
            'relationship': [{
            'uId': 3,
                'name': 'Jasmin',
                'tabs': [{
                'tabId': 2
            }],
                'tasks': [{
                'name': 'Im Jasmin Jacob'
            }]
        }]
    }];
```

Comment: you u declare friend in user, it doesn't return error? since there is no 'friend'?

Comment: @noob take a look at this [ng-repeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
<li ng-repeat="friend in user[0].relationship">{{friend.name}}</li>
```

Comment: I thought relationship is an array too?

Comment: @noob Yes, it's an array, but `friend` is not.

Answer (score 1):

The following code can show "Jeremy" successfully. I hope this would help you.

index.html

```
<body ng-controller="sample">

    <ul ng-repeat="friend in user[0].relationship">
        <li>{{friend.name}}</li>
    </ul>
 </body>
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);


app.controller('sample', function($scope){

$scope.user = [{
    'uId': 1,
    'name': 'eldy',
    'relationship': [
            {'uId':2,
             'name': 'Jeremy',
             'tabs':[
                 {'tabId':1}
             ],
             'tasks':[
                 {'name':'Im Jeremy Lin'}
             ]
            }
        ]
    }]  

});
```